# ANDROID приложение связанное с камерой...?

Tags: android, камера

Передо мной стоит задача создать ANDROID приложение, которое связано с камерой.
Суть приложения заключается в том, что есть определенные фотошаблоны без лиц и с помощью камеры пользователь подгоняет туда свое лицо... Пример приложения - FaceEffect (iOS).

Есть какие нибудь мысли как можно это реализовать ? Если можете что то набросать, то буду рад )
[image: Пример]

Answer (score 0):

На [этой](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView) вьюшке можно как отрисовывать поток с камеры, так и накладывать свои текстуры

Так же есть похожая OpenGL [вьюшка](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/GLSurfaceView)